# Amazon EC2 Nodejs port issue

Tags: amazon-ec2, node.js

I have opened port 80 on my EC2 instance. I have Apache installed, node 8.1.4 is installed on the instance, my files are deployed and node packages installed. But when my server starts (`sudo node index.js`) I get the following error:

```
/var/www/html/index.js:24
app.listen(port, () => {
                  ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:945:3
```

I know I can't run any port under `1024` without root, so my deploy command uses sudo to start the server.

I have tried ports over 1024 (`1234`, `3000` & `8080`) and the server runs as expected, but then when I open those ports on my EC2, the website fails to load.

I currently get the default Amazon/Apache test page on the domain.

Comment: That code has a syntax error... ports are irrelevant until the code is fixed.

Comment: Yeah that's what it looks like, but if I run it on other ports (i.e. `8080`), it works as expected. If I run it locally on port `80` I get: `Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:80` though I have nothing else that I can see on this port.

Comment: Suggest you edit your question to add more detail about things like you you start your server using sudo. If it runs fine on 8080 my best guess is the privilege escalation isn't working as expected.

Comment: You understand that your Apache server runs on port 80 and so your node.js process can't run on port 80 (no matter what you do)?
I assume you want to use Apache as a reverse proxy? Then you need to configure your Apache like this: http://www.codingtricks.biz/run-nodejs-application-apache/
Or you remove the Apache as it isn't necessary if node.js is providing the http server and binds to port 80.

Comment: Sounds like your node runtime was not installed system-wide. That error suggests you're using a nodejs version that supports ES6 syntax. Since you're using sudo, it is not unlikely the node binary you would get doesn't match that of your actual user (eg: using per-user PATHs, like with nvm).